# H2 database db file import

Tags: java, h2

I have a `h2 database` setup in my machine. It contains some tables with data that is needed for a POC.

So the tables etc resides in the `h2.db` physical file in "`users`" directory of my machine.

> I want to share my POC code to one of my friend but I cannot expose my
>   h2 database over network.

Is there a way I can give him the db file and he can just import the tables and data into his own h2 database?

```
He already has h2 setup with some tables of his own. So replacing his db files with mine is not an option.
```

Please guide if there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy a database into an existing one can be done using a SQL dump. H2 database grammar contain the [SCRIPT](http://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#script) function. Generated SQL has to be executed in the target database.